# implementing drag and drop on a table column in html/mvc

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a website that generates tables based on results from a database. I would like the user to have the ability to move the tables (which are nested in cells) around to reorder them.
I found an article [Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/#disqus_thread) which is pretty close. so I tried messing around with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d1s5ur48/) but I can't get much to work.
Here's the JavaScript:

```
    var dragSrcEl = null;

function handleDragStart(e) {
    this.style.opacity = '0.4';

    dragSrcEl = this;
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
}

function HandleDragOver(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }


    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
    return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
    this.classList.Add('over');
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
    this.classList.remove('over');
}

function handleDrop(e) {
    // this/e.target is current target element.

    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
    }

    // Don't do anything if dropping the same column we're dragging.
    if (dragSrcEl != this) {
        // Set the source column's HTML to the HTML of the column we dropped on.
        dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    }

    return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {


    [].forEach.call(cols, function (col) {
        col.classList.remove('over');
    });
}
var cols = document.querySelectorAll('td.DashPad');
[].forEach.call(cols, function (col) {
    col.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
    col.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
});
```

It changes the opacity of the first table upon move, but none of the others. And it does not do drag and drop at all.
Is it possible to do what I am trying to do with table cells that hold tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend jQuery for this. There is a sortable method that takes care of this task pretty easy. All I did was add `class="sortable"` to the outer table and replaced all your javascript with the following:

```
$('.sortable').sortable({items: '.DashPad'});
```

Here is a working copy on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d1s5ur48/3/

More on jQuery sortable:
https://jqueryui.com/sortable/